# Baire Category in Exercise 4 of Chapter 2, Functional Analysis Rudin

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, baire-category

In the next problem of Rudin's book, Functional Analysis,

> Let $L^1$ and $L^3$ be the usual Lebesgue spaces on the unit interval. Prove that $L^2$ is
> of the first category in $L^1$, in the following way
>
> - Put $g_n = n$ on $[0, n^{-3}]$, and show that
>   $$ \int fg_n \to 0  $$
>   for every $f \in L^2$, but not for every $f \in L^1$.

I proved the statement, but I'm having problems to prove this implies that  $L^2$ is of the first category in $L^1$. I think that I can use Banach-Steinhaus theorem, taking $\{\int fg_n \}$ as a collection of linear mappings of $L^1$ to $\mathbb{C}$, but not sure of this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another way would be to use the open mapping theorem: If $L^2$ were of second category in $L^1$ the spaces were equal.